# In Android Emulator, the second time I rotate the device it does not re-orientate

Tags: android, android-emulator

Just wondering why the emulator only works on the first,third and fourth rotations and not the second as well. It rotates but the view is sideways after the second rotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because there is no such screen orientation for the chosen device. Your physical device wouldn't rotate upside down as well. This issue is not related to the emulator itself.

Comment: I never had a smart phone or I would know that. i guess as long as it rotates 90 degrees either direction and back, then it will suffice.